# Return n matching results only when criteria is met, ordered from highest to lowest value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to build an excel formula that searches through a column worth of data, and finds values in the column that are greater or equal to 10, then returns those values from highest to lowest.

I thought this would be as easy as using the following formula:

- `=LARGE($AB$1:$AB$10080>=10,1)`

For some reason however, this simply returns a 0, followed by errors.

To clarify the above, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu1d5.png) is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I expect AC1 to be 12, AC2 to be 11, and then AC3 to be an error. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

```
=LARGE(IF(AB1:AB9>10,AB1:AB9),ROW())
```

The formula is an array formula-CTL+SHIFT+ENTER

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This ended up being it for me, since I do not have access to the FILTER() function. Just wanted to mention to anyone who sees and uses this formula: this only works if the formula is in the first row. If you have the formula in the 8th row for example, you must adjust the formula to ROW()-7.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 365, this will probably work for you:

```
=SORT(FILTER($A$2:$A$29,$A$2:$A$29>10),,-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Top ten numbers greater or equal to 10, sorted descending, using dynamic array formulas in Excel 365. Formula in cell C2, spills down automatically, no copying required.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A1:A31,A1:A31>=10),,-1),SEQUENCE(10))
```

[image]